# ng-show/ng-hide result in element with 0 width and 0 height in safari

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have the following issue that I can't understand. My basic setup is :

```
  <div class="col-xs-12"  data-ng-hide="question.hideSubQuestions">

     //My dynamic-generated contents go here

 </div>
```

Everything works fine in IE, Safari, FireFox, Chrome in Windows. That means the contents are shown as expected when the value **question.hideSubQuestions = false.**

However, when I test my site using Safari in Mac OS or iPhone, the above markup results in the div with **0 height and 0 width** when the value of **question.hideSubQuestions equal false**,which means nothing is shown on the screen.

I have compared resulted styles for the element in both operation systems, everything was identical **except** **the width and the height of the div**. In Windows, the width and the height are what needs to display the div contents, in case of Safari in Mac, the values are **0**.

I have also tested the site using FireFox and Chrome in Mac, everything works as expected. The contents are shown when the value is false.

If you could give me some insights, that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set a value for height and width of the div? can you try setting `auto` and see the result?

Comment: I have tried the auto value, but there is no hope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution. So instead of applying **data-ng-hide="question.hideSubQuestions"** to the parent div, I apply it to the child elements. Which will make the div children display properly when the value **hideSubQuestions** changed.

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer.